# Having issues running a sort macro in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I have a spreadsheet with columns of data. I start a Macro, then sort row B largest to smallest. I copy row A (agent names) and B (sales figures) and paste to another sheet in the same workbook. I then hide row B and then sort Row C form highest to lowest and copy row A and C and paste in my other sheet. I continue this process for another 6 columns (hide the row and just did and copy/paste the next column with the agent name). Here is the problem- when I run the macro, the name of the last sort I did (Person's Name and data) will appear at the TOP of each of the other sorts I pasted into the sheet even though they are not TOP in that category. The rest of the sorted data and names are correct BUT the top name and data comes over the same for each 2 column category I created in the Macro... Help! :)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Please edit and reformat your question.  For example, itemize the steps by prefixing a dash on that line.  There is help when you edit. !

Comment: You can provide a sample here.